# Multiple service with Single endpoint in Client side (Consuming Application)

Tags: wcf

I am having multiple WCF service but while consuming the service in Web application each service having its own end point to access the service. I need to have single end point in my web application to access all the services. Is there any other way except partial class.

Answer (score 0):

No this can't be done. You can't merge multiple services into one endpoint.

You mention a partial class definition. That actually means you merge your different services together and expose them as one single service. This can off course be done and would give you one single access point (since it's just one service).

This way you could still logically separate the code in different files and let the them each implement a single interface. The service as a whole would implement a combined interface of all the different elements and that's what you would expose as a service endpoint.

**--EDIT--**
I personally wouldn't merge the services into one big service because that one big service will have to process all the incoming request. What if you want a certain configuration setting for one service, or you want to do some load balancing and move several services to another server?

If the problem is in maintaning the web.config files, you should have a look at [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). That way you can automate the process of configuring your application for different deployment scenarios.

Comment: Thanks kort. What are the best way . when we are going n number of wcf services. I am consuming the services with add service reference it will create a end point in my web config file. While deploying my website i have change n number of endpoint address in web config file. Is there any other smart way to achieve this.